# Ajax Sending and Retrieving

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been using ajax for a while now and I want to learn more about retrieving data. I only know how to get output by using `callbacks`.

When I use callbacks and I want individual values, I use `split()` or `explode()` so I can get individual value. Is there a better way than this? if I keep using this I think it will get messy if inputs have the same character as the `pattern` for `split`/`explode`.

I want to know how to retrieve data individually via variables, not by `echo` or HTML outputs.

ask if you don't understand my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the output from your PHP page as `jSON`. you can iterate thru the json results with `each` method and get items. That is much cleaner way than doing `split`

A sample

```
$.getJSON("yourphppage.php", function(data){
   $.each(data.ResultSet.Results,function(i,item){
      console.log(data.ResultSet.Results[i].Name);
      console.log(data.ResultSet.Results[i].Age);
   });     
});
```

Assuming you are returning a `JSON` result like the below from your php page

```
{
    "ResultSet": {          
        "ErrorMessage": "No error",
        "Results": [
            {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": "22"
            },
            {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": "22"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** When working with Use **jSONLint**, an awesome webbased tool to tell you whether your JSON is valid or not.

http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `JSON` but may I ask, How do I change/add values of variables in `JSON`? like your sample above, `ResultSet` have 2 objects how do I add another 1 to that?

Comment: @ChristianEricParan: That JSON you will be returning from your PHP Page. Do a google search for creating json from php. Each element in the Results represent a single object. So you can add as many number as of your database records.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax/jquery $.get sample:

```
$.get(
    path_to_your_script. "?run=process_ajax_callback",
    {
        var_ajax: 1, // var sample
        // more vars to your function
    },
    function(response, status) {
        // evaluate response var as a javascript object/array
    },
    'json' // we expect json formatted response
    );
```

Returning values from a PHP function:

```
function process_ajax_callback()
{
    // ...

    $output['var'] = array(1, 2, 3); // var sample

    echo json_encode($output); // encode as json!!!

    exit; // very important (only output from this function)
}
```